# From plugin to theme folder: reference not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

In a given wordpress theme, the javascipt and jquery files are located at /functions/extended/js/

Originally they were located in a plugin folder. I need to retarget the references to a folder within the theme.

my previous code:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) :
    wp_dequeue_script( 'theme-script' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'theme-slider' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/functions.js', array( 'jquery', 'xt-slider' ), '' , true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-slider', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery', ), '' , true );
    wp_localize_script( 'xt-slider', 'featuredSliderDefaults', array(
        'prevText' => __( 'Previous', 'xt' ),
        'nextText' => __( 'Next', 'xt' )
    ));

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'xt_slider_transition' ) ==  'slide' ) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-slider-slide', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/slider-slide.js', array( 'jquery', ), '' , true );

    elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'xt_slider_transition' ) == 'fade' ) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-slider-fade', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/slider-fade.js', array( 'jquery', ), '' , true );
    endif;

endif;
```

my new code doesn't seem to do the trick; the scripts don't get loaded:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) :
    wp_dequeue_script( 'theme-script' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'theme-slider' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-script', bloginfo('template_url') . '/functions/extended/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery', 'xt-slider' ), '' , true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-slider', bloginfo('template_url') . '/functions/extended/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery', ), '' , true );
    wp_localize_script( 'xt-slider', 'featuredSliderDefaults', array(
        'prevText' => __( 'Previous', 'xt' ),
        'nextText' => __( 'Next', 'xt' )
    ));

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'xt_slider_transition' ) ==  'slide' ) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-slider-slide', bloginfo('template_url') . '/functions/extended/js/slider-slide.js', array( 'jquery', ), '' , true );

    elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'xt_slider_transition' ) == 'fade' ) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-slider-fade', bloginfo('template_url') . '/functions/extended/js/slider-fade.js', array( 'jquery', ), '' , true );
    endif;

endif;
```

I've tried get_bloginfo, bloginfo, and get_template_directory_uri(). No bun.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)

Comment: Thanks, Max. Unfortunately 

wp_enqueue_script( 'xt-script', get_template_directory() . '/functions/extended/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery', 'xt-slider' ), '' , true );

etc. still doesn't do it :(

Comment: Possibly a dependency issue? Try swapping the xt-script and xt-slider enqueues?